# Does Sion's shield absorb both physical and magic damage?

Tags: league-of-legends

While reading the skill, it seems like it should absorb both types of damage.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sion's shield (like most other damage shields: Shen's, Janna's) absorb damage from *any* source.

Only Morganna's black shield specifies a damage type (in this case, **magical**).

Comment: As Michael Hopkins notes, Morgana's black shield blocks magic damage, not physical damage.

Comment: Whoops. That's a typo for sure.

Comment: This includes true damage too, on things such as ignite.

Comment: Also important to note that Morgana's shield blocks magical effects, the most common being crowd control. No regular shields like Sion's do this.

Comment: Morgana's shield is basically a spell shield like Banshee's Veil combined with the magic-damage-only shield from Hexdrinker/Maw of Malmortius